# Suitability Analysis with Raster Calculator and Weighted Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, suitability-analysis

I am trying to perform a suitability analysis based on certain criteria which I have rasters of. I would like to use the Raster Calculator function in ArcMap to determine suitability scores in a given area, with some criteria weighted more than others.

For example, one criterion is income, another is tree canopy percentage, and a third is percentage of vacancies. I'd like to give a equal ranking/weight to tree canopy and vacancy and half weight to income.

How should I input this into the raster calculator?

I do understand that if I wanted to give all equal weight I would just input:
 "treeCanopy" + "vacancy" + "income" 
and get my resultant scores in the output raster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the tools "weighted sum" or "weighted overlay" for this if you have the licenses:

http://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/weighted-sum.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-weighted-overlay-works.htm